# Search results File URL in Modern Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, modern-experience, modern-document-library

I am trying to find the column which is used to display search results of a document library in MODERN VIEW. Basically, when I search for a document and search results are presented, a URL is built which can be clicked to open the document. What column (internal name or managed property) is used for that URL?

More details in picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the URL which is displayed when you open the search result document in the browser?

There is no column or managed property for the URL, it is the URL that document opens in the office online.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I mean that URL and it is just not office files. I have files of type .tif, .jpg, .pdf, .msg etc. and all navigates to different URL according to file type. So is there any column in SharePoint which stores this info? How is this URL generated?